# Did Shiraki Rig the Idol Festival Results?

Tags: wake-up-girls

When the winner of the Idol festival is revealed, Shiraki comes up to Hayasaka and says "they won". The disgusted face on Hayasaka is priceless:

[image]

This is right after the announcement that the winners are Akamiso All Stars;
While their performance is not shown, we can clearly see that the crowd is rather normal.

[image]

But on WUG's peformance, the whole stadium comes down:

[image]

We have a scene right before the result is announced, where Shiraki does a kind of power walk from the judge's booth (and the judges sound REALLY nervous), only to be berated by Hayasaka:

[image]

What really happened is not stated, but we have two scenarios:

1) WUG won, but Shiraki rigged the results.

2) The judges really chose Akamiso All Stars, perhaps because of Yoshino missed jump.

I really think that scenario (1) is the most likely, because:

a) it tells a better story
b) explains screenshot 1 (scenario 2 leaves that comment floating on a void).
c) is really on par with Shiraki's ruthless and unscrupulous persona.
d) is a way for Shiraki to strike at the same time both Mayu and Hayasaka (for her daring to step on stage again, and for his "betrayal" on mentoring WUG)

For scenario (2):

a) judges be judges, and [a missed jump can cost a medal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsey_Jacobellis).

So, without any further ADO, and before the flag hunters cry [WOLF](https://www.google.com/search?q=stack%20exchange%20opinion%20based):

### Is there any official / canonical reference that Shiraki rigged the Idol Festival results?

Comment: I don't think so just because the audience went sky high does not mean the other groups had less of it, in fact they don't even show how the audience reacted to other groups as much as it shows WUG to have any base on your statement.

Comment: It did show the reception of Akamiso All Stars' performance, and the crowd is "at rest". Even the colors of the rods are all mixed.

Comment: That would have been the same for WUG if they just showed a few seconds of em.